# Rewriting equation in the form of $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a question, the equation

$x^2+5x-1-dx^2-d=0$

is <s>factorised into</s> rewritten in the form $ax^2+bx+c$ and becomes

$x^2(1-d)+5x-(1+d)=0$

Would somebody be able to tell me how this is done?

Thank you

Comment: It is not a factorisation. It simply consists in grouping terms of like degree, using the property of distributivity: $$x^2+5x-1-dx^2-d=x^2-dx^2+5x-1-d=x^2(1-d)+5x-(1+d).$$

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of us would call this "combining like terms", which is in fact equivalent to factoring common monomial factors.

Hopefully you are aware of the distribution property of multiplying over addition: for all $a, b, c$, $a(b+c) = ab + ac$. This can be used in reverse to combine like terms: $ca + ba = (b+c)a$, or perhaps more familiarly with renamed variables, $ax + bx = (a+b)x = x(a+b)$.

In the given equation, one grouping is made with $x^2 - dx^2 = 1x^2 - dx^2 = x^2(1-d)$. A second grouping is made with $-1 - d = -(1 + d)$. You can check these via distribution if you like. Therefore: $x^2+5x−1−dx^2−d = x^2 - dx^2 + 5x - 1 - d = x^2(1-d) + 5x - (1+d)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 +5x−1−dx^2 −d$$

$$=x^2 −dx^2 +5x−1−d$$

$$=\boxed{\color{blue}{x^2 (1−d)+5x−(1+d)} }$$